# Can Man in the middle open a logged page?

Tags: security, authentication, man-in-the-middle

I know that **man in the middle** (mitm) can be in passive mode : forward, or active mode : modify trafic and forward...

But Can mitm open a page, in firefox for example, to connect on a website where i was **logged**.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you say, the man-in-the-middle can modify the traffic. So when you request a page, he/she can easily return an HTTP 302 to another page, or insert some JavaScript to set the `document.location.href` of your document.

If your traffic is encrypted using https, this is not possible.

Comment: ok i understand. So if i am logged to a site, the hacker in the mitm, even without knowing my password, can browse my personnal page on the site ?

Comment: A hacker that can see you traffic in clear text, can steal your session cookie or access token and do anything you can do.

Comment: ok i see ! thanks  ;) https certificate is needed to protect against that